# My camera flash isn’t working even though is up

Tags: flash, camera

my canon powershot sx210 IS flash isn’t working even though the flash is up.
When i try to take pictures with the flash i can’t i don’t know why[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you check the manual of your camera, page 71?

Comment: What are these pictures supposed to be telling us?

Comment: Your manual is [here](https://files.canon-europe.com/files/soft37674/Manual/PSSX210is_CUG_EN.pdf). Check page 71

Comment: i put these pictures here because i can’t really choose to turn the flash on even though the flash is raised

Comment: i tried every mode but still it doesn’t shoot with the flash

Comment: thank you for sending me manual!! but it doesn’t work also

Comment: i press the right button to turn on the flash but i cant really pick it

Answer (score 3):

You've got the "Indoor" scene mode set (that's the party/cone icon right above the flash with the circle-slash over it), which tries to prevent the flash from firing, [according to the manual](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART108650):

> Prevents camera shake and maintains the subject's true color when shooting under fluorescent or tungsten lightning. The exposure is regulated so as to avoid the use of flash as much as possible.

I would highly recommend you learn to use the four "Creative Zone" modes: P, Tv, Av, or M.

P (Programmable Auto) will set the basic exposure settings on the camera for you, like Auto would, but also lets you override automation of ISO, white balance, and flash.

Tv (Time value; shutter priority mode) would let you specify a shutter speed and the camera auto-adjusts all the other exposure settings.

Av (Aperture value; aperture priority mode) would let you specify an aperture and the camera auto-adjusts the other exposure settings.

M (Manual) lets you drive stick and set all the exposure settings (iso, aperture, shutter speed) yourself explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have Burst Mode on (multiple images for longer shutter presses).  That's incompatible with using the flash.

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at your screenshot, you have that icon that looks like "fireworks" (top right), which might means that flashlight has to be off for shooting that type of scene. Maybe there's a way to switch the mode to "AUTO".

Comment: i put in the Auto mode but still it didn’t work, it tells me to raise the flash but it is already raised.